# How to realize a real waterfall chart

Tags: tableau-api

I know there are a lot of topic which talk about this topic. However, I don't find what I look for. Theres no exact waterfall chart in tableau ?

I ty to achieve a result like this one :

[First example](https://www.google.ch/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fexceltactics.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F11%2FAllLineCharts.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.exceltactics.com%2Fcreate-waterfall-charts-excel%2F&docid=at0_LlEA3qXbVM&tbnid=FfhJfkhc4UX0nM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj3zNDe653YAhUS_qQKHcaeCG8QMwhLKBowGg..i&w=492&h=301&bih=1320&biw=1812&q=waterfall%20chart&ved=0ahUKEwj3zNDe653YAhUS_qQKHcaeCG8QMwhLKBowGg&iact=mrc&uact=8)

[Second example](https://www.google.ch/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffincontrollex.com%2Fimage_templates%2Fexample_3_chart_horizontal_subtotals_en.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.extendoffice.com%2Fdocuments%2Fexcel%2F1515-excel-create-waterfall-chart.html&docid=BJLeAhS9aW-mQM&tbnid=2RKd8njdbo9TsM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj3zNDe653YAhUS_qQKHcaeCG8QMwg1KA4wDg..i&w=750&h=450&bih=1320&biw=1812&q=waterfall%20chart&ved=0ahUKEwj3zNDe653YAhUS_qQKHcaeCG8QMwg1KA4wDg&iact=mrc&uact=8)

[Third one](https://www.google.ch/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffortmarinus.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F01%2FExample-Waterfall-Sample-Chart.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffortmarinus.com%2Fblog%2F1286%2F&docid=eaBkwuMM1b8q0M&tbnid=WtecPyEYnbZ7RM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj3zNDe653YAhUS_qQKHcaeCG8QMwh-KE0wTQ..i&w=709&h=340&bih=1320&biw=1812&q=waterfall%20chart&ved=0ahUKEwj3zNDe653YAhUS_qQKHcaeCG8QMwh-KE0wTQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Let me know it's possible

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246900/tableau-waterfall-chart-with-mixed-colors

Comment: @Siva Did you put a minus one to my question without even answering it properly ? Can you please read it again and withdraw your grade ? Of course, if you have an answer, I'd like to know ...

Comment: you are stupid to assume I have downvoted your question instead I have helped you solve by searching the related link.

Comment: I am not the only one who has viewed the question there are 13 more people who have done it. If you are serious in getting answers you wouldn't have enquired who have downvoted instead you would have asked how the link helps

Comment: Well well, this has quickly escalated. I am sorry that I did think it was you, its really pretty weird to be downvoted for nothing (plus I'm quite new to Stackoverflow). So, I present you my apologizes !! However, you did not answer the question :p

Comment: Nothing as such... here many people will unanimously downvote the questions and answers without leaving a comment on the reason, If we start giving attention on these small issues our purpose of learning will effect, Better to ignore and carry on with the work

Comment: Coming to your question, General waterfall chart is something like the link I have posted and you can use that style, In other case if you are more specific with the visualization and you have any strict requirements then we can work on that. If you have any rough design on how the chart look like post a rough sketch will help in achieving that.

Comment: @Siva : THX !
About the waterfall chart, I have noticed that I made a mistake. Only the first example that I have provided match the criterias. That it to say, an horizontale line with measures around it. Up to see an increase and down to see the opposite. But everything must remain on the same line and not look like stairs. I hope I am clear enough

Comment: Yes clear enough will let you know my response in sometime.

Comment: Great, thx a lot :)

Comment: Check answer and confirm if you are looking is what looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to replicate how the chart should look like but if you need accurate chart then provide dummy data.

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot :), you are really helpful

Comment: I haven't told you the process, Also if you need I can share the tableau workbook.... or if you need the process I can explain in answer. Let me know your choice

Comment: Yes I know, but my boss changes his mind as the bitcoin goes up and down... So it won't be needed anymore. Thx for your help @Siva